# ASP redirect script not added www when needed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My script redirects users who type in domain.com, http://domain.com, http://www.domain.com, etc... to http://www.domain.com...  but does not always work.

When domain.com is used as the url my script does not always redirect correctly to https://www.domain.com ... This happens a lot with IE. I tried added www to my **response.redirect()** but it would add wwwwww.domain.com if they user was being redirected from http://www.domain.com to https:// ... any idea on how I can fix this so that all domain variation will be redirect to https://www.domain.com

```
dim srvname, scrname
if Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") = "off" then 
    srvname = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") 
    scrname = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") 

    Select Case srvname
    Case "localhost"
        'do nothing
    Case "domain.com"
        'do nothing
    Case "www.domain.com"
        'do nothing
    Case Else
        response.redirect("https://" & srvname & scrname) 
    End Select
end if
```

Comment: Where did you write this code? In Application_BeginRequest event?

Comment: @Prawin i writing it for the httpscheck.asp that I'm including in the header for each page `<% %>` .. not using Application_BeginRequest

Comment: I suggest you to kindly print both the srvname and scrname variables and see what output they are providing. Based on the output, you probably need to change the logic of the switch case.. i worked on asp long back and so I lost touch with it :-(

Comment: @Prawin thanks for the advice. I think I have it working... I ended up added the response directly for each case and the redirect url format it should be.

Comment: Is this related to `asp-net-mvc` ? Looks like classic asp. Please use the correct tags. It will help you to get answers from the correct audience.

Comment: @acctman is your issue resolved?